# Netbeans and Eclipse cannot access network resources --

Tags: eclipse, networking, netbeans, ide

I'm trying to update eclipse by going to the help tab, and clicking check for updates...and it just hangs. When I try to do a network install of a plugin I get the same error.

I tried netbeans to see if it was just a problem with eclipse or not, and when I went to the "Available Plugins" window, it could not display any; it told me to check my proxy/network connection. Therefore, I believe the problem has little to do with the IDE I use, but my network itself.

I know for certain that I'm not behind a proxy. What are some possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

What JDK are you using? What OS? I heard about some issues with JDK7 and Windows firewall silently blocking it.